# How i customize GPS and Camera setting in my application using objective-C in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I m the beginner in iphone software development.
I want to make my own customize settings in iphone using objective-C in my own application. In setting UIView i want to perform to set ON/OFF mode of GPS and Camera using UISegment controller/UISwitch.That means i only ON/OFF of GPS and camera setting. I was lot of searching on device setting command(GPS and Camera) using objective-C and now i get frustrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access the GPS system using Core Location.  But don't assume it's GPS, because (a) iPod touches and early iPhones don't have GPS, and (b) if the phone is inside a building it may not be able to get a GPS fix.

You turn Core Location on and off using CLLocationManager.  Use the startUpdatingLocation and stopUpdatingLocation methods to turn it on and off.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Tom Hrrington for helping me.
But there is some any way for ON/OFF the camera?

Comment: The camera is controlled via UIImagePickerController.

This stuff is easy to find in the developer documentation included with Xcode.  Take a look, and save yourself some time.